# Why does apt-get upgrade not install the latest PHP version?

Tags: debian, apt, php

I usualy do

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

in order to keep my **Debian 8.x** server up to date. I also tried `apt-get dist-upgrade`, however, my **PHP** version is still the same one that I installed months ago when I set up my server.

It seems like I only get security updates, but not the current version. I also wonder what else might not be up-to-date (apache, MySQL, etc...).

This has been asked a lot about on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), but I didn't find a solution for Debian yet. I hope this isn't a duplicate!

So, **How do I install the latest PHP version?**

Comment: Which is the up-to-date package for debian (see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/PHP/) and does it match your version? Debian usually is a bit behind with the versions due to their intense stability testing. For the bleeding-edge version either go Debian testing (or even unstable) or manually install versions (which can be a problem with dependencies).

Comment: This is by design. Changes to Debian stable are mostly restricted to security updates. Programs for which security patches cannot easily be backported are upgraded, such as browsers, but these are exceptions. What version of PHP are you using, and what version do you want? Please be specific.

Comment: what is the version you are running?

Comment: I have PHP **5.6.9-0+deb8u1** (according to `phpinfo()`) and Debian **8.1**. I want the PHP version I would get if I installed the server from scratch. And I don't know exactly what the "testing" update branch is and if it's good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` does not install the last PHP version because it is not available in the official debian package repository. At the time of writing the last PHP5 security release is the 5.6.26, the PHP5 version available in [Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5) is 5.6.24 and the PHP5 version available in [sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php5) is also 5.6.24.

You can find newer debian package in third party repositories such as [dotdeb](https://www.dotdeb.org) but at the the time of writing, if you really want the last security release of PHP5 in debian, you have to compile it yourself using the [instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php) from the official PHP website.