# Ubuntu says the most recent version of php is already installed while an old one is installed

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, php

My current version is 7.0.33, I need at least 7.1.33. I have tried `sudo apt-get install php` and it says that the most recent version is already installed. I have also tried manually installing the package and changing repositories and no solution.
Here is the output:

> php ya está en su versión más reciente (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).

Comment: Please keep in mind that it could be useful to translate error messages if they're not in english.
Did you try to search for similiar questions here? Maybe this may help (event it's older and for Debian): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225225/why-does-apt-get-upgrade-not-install-the-latest-php-version

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04, php 7.0.33 is really the most recent version.

```bsh
ubuntu@ ~> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
ubuntu@ ~> php -v
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.12 (cli) ( NTS )
```

If you need 7.1 series, either install from a PPA or update your ubuntu release to 18.04

```bsh
root@ ~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
root@ ~# php -v
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2020 18:39:59) ( NTS )
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried  ondrej/pho PPA and nothing

Comment: @LuisRivera Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @LuisRivera: You didn't mention any thing about your system and what steps exactly you did. Since you are new, I can understand it. Try first the command `sudo apt install php7.1`. If you still face a problem, please paste everything you have done, and don't paste words, paste the exact commands and output like I did in my answer